# How to create the 3D logo like this with Adobe Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text

I need help creating a logo like this.

I have tried Skew option and Perspective option but those didn't work.

[image]

This is the image I have tried below.

[image]

Comment: Hi Envira Phani, it would help if you posted an example of what you tried so we can better help to see why your attempted didn't work.

Comment: I would use Illustrators Perspective Grid to make something like this. If you have to use Photoshop, have you tried Distort Transform tool?

Comment: @AndrewH Hey buddy,Thanks for the reply\, i would post a pic of the image i have tried. http://i.imgur.com/ERhJaz7.png , here it is. Please check, regards

Comment: Are you trying to go for an exact style of the original graphic? The only way to achieve something like that (To my knowledge) would be to rasterize the type and use the distort transform tool. I think if you want your question off of hold is you will have to describe what you have and why that didn't work.

Comment: Instead of SKEW you want DISTORT

Comment: cant be that hard. DA01 is right, it's distort and not skew (even tho you can combine both to create this or similar effect). Also the shadow is custom made and not generated by layer effects

Comment: Chances are the original was done in Illustrator, not Photoshop. [Illustrator offers some better options](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/13564/what-are-some-good-tips-on-how-to-extrude-text-in-adobe-illustrator/13566#13566)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In Photoshop**

If you're going for a similar style of the original artwork and using Photoshop then you will want to use the `Distort Tool`.

Write out your text. I quickly used the pen tool to show an example of the original text.

You have to turn your type layer into a smart object. Right click on the type layer in the layers panel and click `Convert to Smart Object`.
- Tip by Ryan

<strike>You must first make sure your **type layer is rasterized**. Right click on the type layer in the layers panel and click `Rasterize Type`.</strike>

I have all of my shapes in a group layer. Transform the layer `Ctrl + T`. Right click on the canvas and select `Distort`. You will now be able to individually move each corner to create the desired perspective.

[image: using the distort tool]

You will see the bottom right corner is slightly lifted upwards and the top right anchor point is moved down more.

For the rest of the image. Just add a stroke and use the pen tool to get the other black shapes.

**In Illustrator**

I would suggest creating this effect in Illustrator using the Perspective Grid Tool

Comment: Don't rasterize your type. That's dated. Select all of your type and convert it to a Smart Object instead. That way you can right click the smart object -> Edit Contents and still make changes to your text.

Answer (score 1):

1. Type and arrange your text.

[image: Compose Type]

2. Apply an `Outside Stroke` making it bigger and bigger until everything is covered. Mine is rounded because I used a round font, the text in yours is square because its a square font:

[image: Stroke]

3. Select your text layers together and Convert to Smart Object
4. Then Edit > Transform > Perspective and in the same one can do a slight skew:

[image: Perspective Transform]

5. Because its a Smart Object you can right click the Smart Object Layer to edit contents if needed, save and close after, and it reflects in original:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another way to produce a 3D effect in Photoshop similar to your example is to create your text, apply the stroke, convert to smart object, and distort as explained above. Then switch to the Move tool and, holding down the Alt key, repeatedly press the right arrow key (I did it about 20 times) to arrive at the desired depth. Which arrow key you press determines the direction of the depth.

[image]

You can also press two arrow keys simultaneously (the up and the right, say) to get depth in more than one direction.

[image]

Comment: Thank you guys for the responses, I have tried distort option as mentioned and i have got it right. Thanks again for all you guys, every answer you have posted works :)